# Cursor for an Image always returns null

Tags: android, uri, android-cursor, mediastore

I'm storing a picture from my Camera like this:

```
String newName = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom())
                    .toString(24);
File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    CameraActivity.DIR_PICTURES);
mydir.mkdirs();
fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, newName + ".png");
out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

where `CameraActivity.DIR_PICTURES` stands for `"com.korcholis.testapp/pictures"`. Nothing special, in my opinion. The problem comes when I try to get some information about this image. Somewhere else in my code:

```
Uri selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(sample.getPicture()));
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
mediaScanIntent.setData(selectedImage);
getSherlockActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent); //Now it's in the Gallery
selectedImage = Uri.parse("content://"+(new File(sample.getPicture()).toString()));
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
Cursor cursor = getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if(cursor != null)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    Log.i("ImageTest", cursor.getString(columnIndex));
    cursor.close();
}
else
{
    Log.i("ImageTest", selectedImage .toString());
}
```

The **else Log** returns `content:///storage/emulated/0/com.korcholis.testapp/pictures/1aaf2e587kg519cejk88ch6hle372.png`, which is normal, but the cursor is `null` at `cursor.moveToFirst()`. It looks like the cursor can't find the image. However, when getting into the Storage through a file manager, the image is easily found in the correct folder. I've also checked that the file actually exists when using `file://`, and it does. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 5/8/2013:**
I've kept looking for a solution, however this looks impossible. I've read in other threads that `file://` isn't a good enough Uri to look for using `getContentResolver()`, so I tried using `content://` instead. This, despite my efforts, isn't going as well as expected. I edited the last codeblock to the current code I'm using. I've even tried adding it to the gallery, so it could count as an item in the "resolved content list".

Comment: you say you the problem comes when you want some information about the file. I understand that you want something about the image somewhere else in the code. exactly what do you need at that point ?

Comment: I want to grab the `MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION` for your [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397279/implement-a-take-picture-crop-or-use-premade-intents). Just that. I am also able to grab the picture and set as a drawable in an `ImageView`, so the picture exists.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a cursor, since you only need to find the orienataion of one image you could do this :

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImage);
exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
if(orientation == 3 || orientation == 6 || orientation == 8 ){ 
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
   if (orientation == 6)
      matrix.postRotate(90); 
   else if (orientation == 3)
      matrix.postRotate(180);  
   else if (orientation == 8)
      matrix.postRotate(270);
   result = Bitmap.createBitmap(result, 0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap 
}
```

Comment: hello @kushwaha I need to find orientation of image and using `ExifInterface` is always returning me 0. Could you help me why it is always returning zero.

Comment: This method works only if a camera app saves a picture with exif data, which is rather rare nowadays. If there's no EXIF, it returns `null`.